# Dynamic website with different images via HttpListener in C#

Tags: c#, html, http, web, httplistener

I created a simple HttpListener:

```
        string prefix = "http://localhost:63297/";
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
        WriteLog("Added prefix " + prefix);
        listener.Start();
        WriteLog("Http-Server started...");
        HttpListenerContext context;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                context = listener.GetContext();
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(() => ClientCommunication(context));
                clientThread.Start();
            }
        }
```

With ClientCommunication being:

```
HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
string responseString = "????";
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
Stream output = response.OutputStream;
output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
output.Close();
```

It already displays "????" when I open localhost:63297 but I have no clue how to proceed.

My question now: Is there a way that if I open http://localhost:63297 in my browser I can dynamically "show" pictures with a press of a button from inside the program?

For example: I have 3 different pictures in my program and have the "website" open. I press "picture 2" inside my program and it displays in my browser. I can now press "picture 1" in my program and it changes the picture to 1 in my browser. I tried finding solutions / ways to do it but sadly have no clue since I've never done anything similar.

Comment: Perhaps build a webapi, where getimage has as a parameter a id, which returns the actual filelocation / base64 encoding. This would be relevant: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Katana/WebApi/ReadMe.txt